# How to use a trained binary file in golearn

Tags: go

I have this trainingdata in a csv:

```
RoomType, HasWater
bathroom, true
living_room, false
storage, false
kitchen, true
...
```

Using golearn to train data. Decission tree (not sure if decission tree is the correct one?)

```
func TrainData() {
...
    //Do a training-test split
    trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(rawData, 0.50)
    tree := trees.NewID3DecisionTree(0.6)
...
    tree.Save('decissiontree.h')
}
```

So I have saved the result to this binary file.

I want be able to query my file with a label (a roomType) of the probability the room has water or not.

```
func HasWater(roomType: string):float64 {
    tree := trees.NewID3DecisionTree(0.6)
    tree.Load("model.h");
   // What next??
}
```

I don't find any examples in golearn how you actually use your trained binary file. I guess I should load the file. But then what?

Sorry for basic question. Totally new to ML (and GO).

Answer (score 2):

You have a `training.csv` which you used for training and testing if your model is working as expected. Once your model is working as expected you saved it for later use.

`training.csv`

```
RoomType, HasWater
bathroom, true
living_room, false
storage, false
kitchen, true
...
```

```golang
// Reading training.csv file
testData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("training.csv", false)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// spliting train and test data
trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(testData, 0.50)
// used the trainData for training model
...
// testing if model is working as expected
predictions, err := tree.Predict(testData)
...
// Saved model for later work
tree.Save('decissiontree.h')
```

Now the model is trained and working as expected. we need to test model if it is working on unknown data different from training and test data
you can load the previous saved trained binary and use that for testing unknown data for prediction

`unknown.csv`

```
RoomType, HasWater
ocean, true
truck, false
car, false
lake, true
...
```

```golang
tree := &DecisionTreeNode{}
err := tree.Load("model.h");

unknownTestData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("unknown.csv", false)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

predictions, err := tree.Predict(unknownTestData)
```

- Example to create data yourself and pass to model for predition

```golang
// Create a new, empty DenseInstances
newInst := base.NewDenseInstances()

// Create some Attributes 
attrs := make([]base.Attribute, 2)
attrs[0] = new(base.CategoricalAttribute)
attrs[0].SetName("0")
attrs[1] = new(base.CategoricalAttribute)
attrs[1].SetName("1")

// Add the attributes
newSpecs := make([]base.AttributeSpec, len(attrs))
newSpecs[0] = newInst.AddAttribute(attrs[0])
newSpecs[1] = newInst.AddAttribute(attrs[1])

newInst.Extend(4)

newInst.Set(newSpecs[0], 0, newSpecs[0].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("RoomType")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[1], 0, newSpecs[1].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("HasWater")))

newInst.Set(newSpecs[0], 1, newSpecs[0].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("ocean")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[1], 1, newSpecs[1].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("true")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[0], 2, newSpecs[0].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("truck")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[1], 2, newSpecs[1].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("false")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[0], 3, newSpecs[0].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("lake")))
newInst.Set(newSpecs[1], 3, newSpecs[1].GetAttribute().GetSysValFromString(strings.TrimSpace("true")))

predictions, err := tree.Predict(newInst)
```

Here i only used `CategoricalAttribute` but there are more Attributes type available in golearn like `FloatAttribute`, `BinaryAttribute`

**Note:** `unkwown.csv` includes data which is not included in training or test data which can be used to check how well model is performing on unknown data.

Comment: Could you give example of how this testData, newTestData is formatted?

Comment: @Joe Included explanation if any issue please let me know

Comment: Is this really the offical way of predicting? Generate a phyiscal file on each request? Seems odd. I'm coming from a javascript background and there the normal thing would be just to send in an array of unknowns, e.g ['ocean', 'car'] and get a response back with a probability of ocean and car.

Comment: there are some cases you can check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-are-you-planning-to-retrain-your-machine-learning-model-5349eb0c4706) guide for more info.

Comment: there is no need to retrain and save model again and again until the model is predicting correctly.

Comment: Nah I have a perfectly trained model. I don't want to compare how test data performs. I want to use my trained model in production. User sends in data via rest api I just want to return the predicated result. I don't understand why I need to save the user input to a csv file before I can use it agains the trained file.

Comment: you can directly pass user input to predict without saving it in csv but golearn required it to be in format

Comment: This is what I am asking. Can you provide an example in answer?

Comment: @Joe i have updated my anwser on how to create data yourself and pass to perdict func.

Comment: 20+ lines of code? Can't you just do something like var prediction = tree.Load('tree.h').predict('bathroom') // => 85%?

Comment: `golearn` is still in development phase it does have any `func` to that you can create your own `func` as per your requirement and use it for your work, like in golearn there is csv `func` wrapper that reads file and create structure that is used internally by `golearn`

Comment: What's the point to train data if you can't actually use your trained data? Like creating a database with only write operations and no read.

Comment: model is like a child which does not know anything it needs to be trained and checked if it is learning correctly. on start model does'nt know anything about how your data look like, what it need to take out of data, what will be the prediction, etc for that it need to train and then we need to test that what it had learned is it correct or not.

Comment: Yes. But after this step. We trained it. We've validated it etc. Now we want to put the stuff into production and actually start deliver results to end users via rest api's. This code seems extremly cumbersome.

Comment: you can either use more mature library like `scikit-learn` or you can ask the `golearn` dev for the improvement but it will take time and for that time you can use this code modified version when that improvement comes then you can remove extra code and use `golearn` version.

Comment: @Joe for other `golang` machine learning libraries you can check [here](https://awesome-go.com/#machine-learning).

Comment: Yes I did som research. Golearn is the most generic and most stars. Yet, it still can't query it's on trained model yet..

Comment: some other library you can check for decision tree [ddt](https://github.com/sgrodriguez/ddt).

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this is just create a csv file with the values, which you want to make predictions on and run a `Predict` upon those value(s):

```golang
    testData, err = base.ParseCSVToInstances("test.csv", false)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, testDataInstance = base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(testData, 1.0)

    preds = tree.Predict(testDataInstance)

    fmt.Println(preds.RowString(0))
```

Where `test.csv` is the following:

```
bathroom, false
```

Comment: Hm. Generate a file to make a predict? Make no sense?

Comment: Yeah, I find this a pretty cumbersome solution as well, but I couldn't find anything better for it. The package itself felt a bit under documented as well + it's not that actively maintained either. But I hope somebody will come up with a better answer though :crossed-fingers: